# Generate Dogecoin Keys

Tags: dogecoin

1. Can I use the same method of generating Bitcoin private key and public key for Dogecoin?
2. After No.1 above is complete, does Dogecoin support compressed public key?
3. How do I generate Dogecoin address from the result of No.1 public key?
4. Can I use the same Bitcoin signing method on Dogecoin?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume the private key is **0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff**

1. Both Bitcoin and Doge can share a common private key and use the same Elliptic Curve algorithms to synthesize public keys.

   Here is a working example for how one can synthesize an **uncompressed** public key for Bitcoin or Doge from a common 256-bit hexadecimal encoded integer private key.

   % echo "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff" | bx ec-to-public -u

   **040d47568a5e517067a2836c3823fbc58169a7662bfae934a4d41da3e23c98d816e7202dd702ffe038147f78aee4973a581972960a1460312ffb6f3f0f13d4a52c**
2. Here is how a **compressed public key** can be calculated for either Bitcoin or Doge. Notice the public key is half the size.

   % echo "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff" | bx ec-to-public

   **020d47568a5e517067a2836c3823fbc58169a7662bfae934a4d41da3e23c98d816**
3. Computation of compressed and uncompressed Bitcoin and Doge addresses. One must examine this [**table**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#bip44-altcoin-version-mapping-table) to understand the **version** values [-v flags] that must be different for Bitcoin-based altcoins used such as Doge. Unsure if Doge fully supports compressed addresses, but is very likely to do so if the Doge source code forks are updated when Bitcoin is updated. Compressed addresses have been supported by Bitcoin for over 4 years.

   % echo "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff" | bx ec-to-public | bx ec-to-address -v 0

   **1PbStXjfDNBU6FZA2iSeisVWwCFN9GK1eQ** (is a compressed address)

   % echo "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff" | bx ec-to-public | bx ec-to-address -v 30

   **DTjYRngJWn5kdFjkmJSDGdf7pKyfUnVnGg** (is a compressed address)

   % echo "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff" | bx ec-to-public -u | bx ec-to-address -v 0

   **1NGoV1EGZrwM7yvUYqRC7TMBMj7ftpjR2B** (is an uncompressed address)

   % echo "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff" | bx ec-to-public -u | bx ec-to-address -v 30

   **DSQu2GAusGqdez75HRQkfDWnErqyEB4Bov** (is an uncompressed address)
4. Believe the answer is yes.